# Is it possible to turn on/off optimizations for the .NET compiler in godbolt?

Tags: c#, compiler-options, godbolt

Is it possible to turn on/off optimizations for the .NET compiler in godbolt?

I've tried -optimize and Optimize as per the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/code-generation), and some other fruitless attempts, but I don't see a difference.

With .NET (main) it always seems to optimize. The other one (.NET 7.0.105) does not seem to (see below example). However, it does remove some duplicate code that is force inlined from different source functions (when comparing with a hand-optimized version). This confuses me; are such optimizations done even in debug?

```cs
    static int Test(int a)
    {
        a = a+2;
        a = a+2;
        return a;
    }
```

.NET (main):

```
MyClass:Test(int):int (FullOpts):
       lea      eax, [rdi+0x04]
       ret
```

.NET 7.0.105:

```
MyClass:Test(int):int:
       add      edi, 2
       add      edi, 2
       mov      eax, edi
       ret
```

Comment: You are compiling with different options.  One looks like x64 and the other x32.  This is not optimization.  It is the addressing mode of the micro.

Comment: Apply `[MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.NoOptimization)]` attribute to the method instead.

Comment: I didn't specify any options, I am using whatever godbolt is using as default.

Of course an attribute will help for testing purposes, but that's not very practical

Comment: The difference being 64 vs 32 bits does not explain why it optimizes the +2 in one case and not in the other, that certainly looks like an optimization